# How do i write the exponential decay for this?

Tags: exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

At this time, the number of people who use a particular health plan is 19,250. The number of people who use the plan is expected to decrease by 14% each year.

Write an equation of the type you just identified that models the number of people who use the health plan, N, as a function of time in years from now, t.

Comment: It is customary to show what you have attempted to do yourself as well. Have you an idea?

Comment: I had attempted to write it out many times but it was a computer program that was being picky so my teacher would see I tried many forms of the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of people using the plan decreases by $14\%$ each year, then the number of people that will remain on the plan is $1 - 14\% = 86\%$. So, it can be modeled as

$$N (t) = 19250 (0.86)^t$$

where $t$ is in years.

Comment: Omg thank you so much